# Unable to upload file from on server to another

Tags: java, spring-boot, file-upload

I am trying to upload a file on my server to another server. While doing this 
I am getting this error : `Resolved [org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException: Required request part 'file' is not present]`

I have put the 'file' key in my body. I am unable to figure out why this is hapenning.

Uploading Server:

```
                HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
                headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
                MultiValueMap<String, Object> body
                        = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
                body.add("file", Paths.get("pathToFile").toFile());
                HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity
                        = new HttpEntity<>(body, headers);

                RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
                ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate
                        .postForEntity(url, requestEntity, String.class);
```

Server that we are uploading to:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.ALL_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<ResponseDTO> solveUsingJar(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I share some code to upload a file one server to another server.**

STEP-1 : Upload a file in Server-1 :

```
@PostMapping("/upload/profile")
public UploadFileResponse uploadProfileImg(@RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file)
{       
    return fileService.uploadProfileImg(file);
}
```

STEP-2 : Upload that file in Server-2 using RestTemplate.

```
public String upload(MultipartFile file) throws IOException 
{
    ResponseEntity<UploadFileResponse> response = null;

    try
    {
        File convFile = new File(file.getOriginalFilename());           

        convFile.createNewFile();       

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(convFile);          
        fos.write(file.getBytes());
        fos.close();

        LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();

        String uploadURI = KeyConstant.FILE_UPLOAD_API_URI+"/file";     // Server-2(file Directory) FILE_UPLOAD_API_URI : http://27.34.2.33:28181/upload/file

        map.add("file",  new FileSystemResource(convFile));

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();

        headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);

        HttpEntity<LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(map, headers);

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

        response = restTemplate.exchange(uploadURI, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, UploadFileResponse.class);      
    }
    catch(Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}

    return response.getBody();
}
```

STEP-3 : Server-2 File Upload Rest Controller :

```
@PostMapping("/upload/file")
public UploadFileResponse uploadFileByDirectory(@RequestPart(value = "file") MultipartFile file)
{
    return this.amazonClient.uploadFilebyDirectory(KeyConstant.AMAZON_S3_PATH, file);
}
```